# How to access UART or serial sensors?

Tags: serial, rangefinder

I want to connect [ir range finder](https://www.jenoptik.com/products/defense-and-security/laser-rangefinders/oem-modules-system-integration/dlem) (`dlem 20`) with the system running Linux kernel. It looks like they don't provide any kind of SDK or drivers for their products. So how should I get data from such sensors with UART connectivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So according to the datasheet from the link provided, the Data interface is indeed UART (LVTTL 3.3V). The datasheet also says it has 2 Modes of operation: Single measurement, continuous ranging 1Hz to 25Hz.

The datasheet does not go into the details of the application layer (ie. the commands and structure of the data in those commands), let alone the baud rate.

After reading the website I would surmise that the application layer information is a bit secretive - being that its primary application is for military use. You would have to contact the company directly for access to that information.

Comment: ok thanks for suggesting this things. but as u mentioned arduino i'm not using arduino right now i'm testing all software parts in my laptop running linux kernel patched with xenomai 3.0.5 for hard real time capability, and will be using some mini pc for real model or product. acc to this: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/15796/rs-232-422-uart-usb-sensor-access-code-same?noredirect=1#comment25511_15796 since uart is serial, do i need some extra information to use the sensor since linux has already built in serial drivers? sorry i'm less experienced with hardware part.