# RS-232/422, UART, usb sensor access code same?

Tags: serial

Is the method to access all the sensors with RS-232/422, uart and usb sensors can be done in same way? Or by converting rs-232 to usb, uart to usb can they be programmed in same as usb from linux?

For example [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22545/how-to-connect-to-a-serial-port-as-simple-as-using-ssh) link provides way to access such port from linux command line and program. so my question is considering i have another serial device/sensor with same type of connetivity i.e serial would it not be same to access that device in same method as described in above link.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you please edit your question and clarify. Thanks.

Comment: yes, the method is the same in the sense that you require a driver for each device.

Comment: but linux has already built in drivers for serial device like above, so do i need extra driver if i want to use some new type of device/sensor which uses above mentioned port but is new for my system?

Comment: Hi Dinesh Lama, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RS232 and RS432 should be handled identically since they are both merely physical standards (voltage, cabling, etc) and appear to the computer identically. They would even have the same device under Linux.

The USB is just slightly different when opening it up because it has a different device associated with it. Once you've found that for your system, it should be the same.

They all should act like serial connections.